# getBoundingClientRect during throttled scroll event handling

Tags: javascript, scroll, settimeout, getboundingclientrect

I faced an issue during my project developing, it's related to a difference between `getBoundingClientRect` values with and without preventive break points during debugging. Trying to minimize repro, I got following.

```
const scrollHandler = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const top = document.getElementById('test').getBoundingClientRect().top;
    console.log(top);
  });
};

document.getElementById('viewport').addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler);
```

where the `viewport` is just scrollable div with fixed height. The content of the `viewport` is big enough to be able to fire at least one scroll event. I also created [Plunker demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/BuUzak/). All magic happens inside of `setTimeout` callback.

Now the steps. Success scenario.

1. Set break point at the beginning of the `setTimeout` callback.
2. Fire scroll event.
3. Make "step over" to obtain `top` value.
4. Execute `document.getElementById('test').getBoundingClientRect().top` in the console.
5. The results of 3 and 4 **are the same**.

Failed scenario.

1. Set break point at the end of the `setTimeout` callback.
2. Fire scroll event.
3. Get the value of `top` variable (no action is needed).
4. Execute `document.getElementById('test').getBoundingClientRect().top` in the console.
5. The results of 3 and 4 **are not the same**.

To avoid any misunderstanding with this repro, I recorded a [short demo movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtmxNRW87Ng) with the above steps.

In my project I'm doing calculations in a similar environment (throttled scroll events) and getting wrong results that don't match expectations. But when I debug it, I'm getting different picture; a preventive break point fixes calculations.

Is it a bug or known issue? Or did I miss something? should I refuse to use `getBoundingClientRect` in such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what it is that you are looking for but assume your animation on scroll isn't working as expected.

There is a tip on throttling scroll [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/throttle-scroll-events/) that is incorrect. Let's say you throttle to every 30 milliseconds. If page stops scrolling 25 milliseconds after last animation then you're stuck with a scroll position 25 milliseconds before it stopped scrolling.

Maybe a better way to do it is this (can test in the console on this page):

```
var ol = document.querySelectorAll("ol")[2];
window.onscroll = ((lastExecuted)=>{
    const expensiveHandler = e => {
      lastExecuted=Date.now();
      //do some animation maybe with requestAnimationFrame
      //  it may prevent overloading but could make animation
      //  glitchy if system is busy
      console.log("1:",ol.getBoundingClientRect().top);
    };
    var timerID
    return e=>{
      if(Date.now()-lastExecuted>19){
        //only animate once every 20 milliseconds
        clearTimeout(timerID);
        expensiveHandler(e);
      }else{
        //make sure the last scroll event does the right animation
        //  delay of 20 milliseconds
        console.log("nope")
        clearTimeout(timerID);//only the last is needed
        timerID=setTimeout(e=>expensiveHandler(e),20);
      }
    }
})(Date.now())
```